# Trying to get result from FileReader in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, callback, filereader

I am using FileReader in ExtJs and i want to return a boolean after reading the file and compare lines number with a constant. The problem is that i cant get the result in on-load event. I think i need to use callback but i dont know hot to write the ExtJs function with callback. Any help, please?

### My function:

```
fileHasAdmittedSize: function() {
    var me = this;
    var file = me.getView().down('#newImsiForm').down('filefield').getEl().down('input[type=file]').dom.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function() {
        return function(e) {
            var match = e.target.result.match(/\r?\n/g);
            if (match.length > 4000000) {
                Ext.MessageBox.show({
                    title: 'ERROR',
                    msg: WebUI.Msg.imsiMaxFileSize,
                    icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                });
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        };
    })(file);
    reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

If i call this function the result is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Using a FileReader object to get the size of a file is overkill, you can just use the size property of the File object.

```
fileHasAdmittedSize: function() {
    var file = me.getView().down('#newImsiForm').down('filefield').getEl().down('input[type=file]').dom.files[0];
    if (file.size > 4000000) {
        Ext.MessageBox.show({
            title: 'ERROR',
            msg: WebUI.Msg.imsiMaxFileSize,
            icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
            buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
        });
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
}
```